# C# ApplicationBase return value letter case differs from folder path on disk

Tags: c#, .net

I use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase` to get the running exe's folder path on disk. It returns

`G:\VSProjects\WorkStation\bin\x64\Debug\` (note the uppercase S in WorkStation)

but the actual path is

`G:\VSProjects\Workstation\bin\x64\Debug\` (note the lowercase s in Workstation), which shows in file explorer.

I know Windows does not distinguish letter case when handler paths. But why `ApplicationBase's` value is not the same as path the exe lies in.

The exe's project name is WorkStation (upper case S), does the project name involvs in path concat?

Comment: Is it possible that the folder's original name was "WorkStation" and then you renamed it to "Workstation"? Windows gets a bit crazy when you rename a folder to the same name but with different capitalization.

Comment: @Gusman Not exactly, there used to be a WorkStaion folder. I rename it to WorkStation.old and clone a new one from GIT named Workstation. Is that the case?

Comment: Yep, that's it, Windows has re-used the old file system entry. It's not a C# problem, it's a Windows problem. Very annoying, I have suffered it.

Comment: @Gusman Many thanks. It does be very confusing. Is there a way to "refresh" Windows' path record?

Comment: None that I know... sorry.

Comment: @Gusman That is already a great help. You may leave a reply as answer which will be marked as accepted.